# How to print a page loading message before the header using CGI Perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I want to show a message which will read 'Loading..Please wait' before the actual content of my webpage is along with the header is loaded. However on Apache 2.2.15, without printing the header first, no print message can be shown. Below is the code:
(Perl version 5.14.1, CGI version : 3.52) :

```
use CGI;

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

#print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print '<pre>'. " This is before header"  .'</pre>';
print qq[<DIV id="loading" style="position:absolute; font-family:arial; 
font-size:16; left:0px; top:0px; background-color:red; layer-background- 
color:white; height:100%; width:100%;">
<TABLE width=100%><TR><TD><B>Loading... Please wait!</B></TD></TR></TABLE>

</DIV>];



my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header();

print $q->start_html();

warn "this is test header issue script \n";
print "Hello Everybody .. !";
print $q->end_html();
```

If I print 'content-type:text/html' at the top, then I am able to show the loading message, but that also prints the content-type at the top which I do not want. 
Is there a Perl way to achieve this ? 
This is just a short and simplified example of my actual code, so after printing the loading message, the control of the code won't proceed further, please ignore that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how CGI works.

The header goes before content.

See [RFC3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-5):

> 6.2.  Response Types

> The response comprises a message-header and a message-body, separated
> by a blank line.  The message-header contains one or more header
> fields.  The body may be NULL.

> ```
>  generic-response = 1*header-field NL [ response-body ]
> ```

What you want requires a client solution: The first response returns the interstitial. Then, a subsequent request loads the finished page. These days, this is done using AJAX calls. In the old days, we used to do full page reloads.

See [Randal Schwartz's "Watching long processes through CGI"](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html).